# Function to escape some characters for C++ string

Tags: c++, string, escaping

I need a function to escape some characters inside a `std::string` and so i made this:

```
static void escape(std::string& source,const  std::vector<std::string> & toEscape, const std::string& escape){
    //for each position of the string
    for(auto i = 0; i < source.size(); ++i){
        // for each substring to escape
        for(const auto & cur_to_escape : toEscape){
            // if the current position + the size of the current "to_escape" string are less than the string size and it's equal to the substring next of the i'th position
            if(i + cur_to_escape.size() < source.size() && source.substr(i, cur_to_escape.size()) == cur_to_escape){
                // then for each char of the current "to_escape", escape the current character with the "escape" string given as parameter
                /*
                 *  source = asd
                 *  toEscape = {"asd"}
                 *  escape = \
                 *  -> asd -> \asd -> \a\sd -> \a\s\d 
                 * */
                for(auto z = 0; z < cur_to_escape.size(); ++z){
                    source.insert(i, escape);
                    i+=escape.size();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and to test it i've used this:

```
int main() {
    std::string s = "need to escape \" , \\ and \n .";
    std::cout<<s;
    escape(s, {"\n", "\\", "\""}, "\\");
    std::cout<<"\n\n final string: "<<s;
}
```

and the output is

```
final string: need to escape \" , \\ and \
 .
```

and so the `\n` is not been escaped as intended... and i can't find the problem... any guesses?

Comment: This is fundamentally wrong. This basic, trivial task should not require even two, and definitely not ***three*** nested `for` loops? It's not even worth trying to understand that attempted logic here, it's obviously wrong. Working this out in my head, something like this should need only take about four lines of code. One range-iteration. One `if` statement. Two `push_back`s. Oh, and a `return` statement. Make it five lines of code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sorry, cut in a unordered container, the search of a string long m in a string long n is n^2-m, one loop is to go through the string, one is to go through the string that i need to escape, and one to escape char by char of the string i need escape if it's longer than 1......... but if you thing the you can do it in 5 lines, i will be more than happy to check it out and thanks to you for the helps, so feel free to show me that i'm wrong

Comment: You wrote code to prepend a backslash to every character that needs to be escaped, and your code does exactly that. Computers to what you tell them to do, not what you want them to do.

Comment: @BessieTheCow yes but new line is only represented by "\n" but in the string has no "\" and so i was wondering if there is a way to transform each \n to \\n

Comment: Then you have to add a special case for line breaks and change them to `\n` instead of just appending a backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*“and so the \n is not been escaped as intended”* Yes, it is: the new-line character is there, as expected. If you expect an `'n'` character, you are wrong. `'\n'` is a convention used to represent the "invisible" character New-Line (`NL`).

Here's a cleaner way to write the same thing (**[try it](https://www.ideone.com/G2Qv0A)**):

```
std::string escape(const char* src, const std::set<char> escapee, const char marker)
{
  std::string r;
  while (char c = *src++)
  {
    if (escapee.find(c) != escapee.end())
      r += marker;
    r += c; // to get the desired behavior, replace this line with: r += c == '\n' ? 'n' : c;
  }
  return r;
}
//...
std::string r = escape("\"this\" is a test\nthis is the second line", { '"', '\n' }, '\\');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working code, but it is not optimal and can be made faster but probably also bigger.

```
void escape(std::string& source, const  std::vector<std::string>& to_escape, const std::string& escape) { 
    // for each substring to escape
    for (const auto &e : to_escape) {
        auto pos = source.find(e);
        while (pos != std::string::npos) {
            auto to_replace = escape+e;
            if (e=="\n") to_replace = escape+"n";
            else if (e=="\t") to_replace = escape+"t";
            source.replace(pos, e.size(), to_replace);
            const auto old_pos = pos;
            pos = source.find(e, old_pos + to_replace.size());
        }
    }
}
```

[Live Code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d5af5b630b6a9e8)

Comment: "not comple" what means? (thank you, i'll check it out)

Comment: the problem is that here you are replacing only the first occurrence of the "const auto& e", not all, and so of "\n\n"  will be escaped only the first "\n"

Comment: thank, but now with "escape(s, {"\n", "\\", "\""}, std::string(1,'\\'));" it escapes the "\n" with "\\n".. any guesses?

Comment: oh that's because it first replace the "\n" and then the "\" and so the "\" are doubled... i think that i just need to take out the "\\" in the to_escape vector and add at the begging a "replace all the *delimiter* with *delimiterdelimiter*"