# std::replace on std::string invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, replace, compiler-errors

I'm using `std::replace` to replace all occurrence of a string with another one, and so this is my code:

```
static void escape(std::string& source,std::map<std::string, std::string> escape_map){
    for(auto&[from, to] : escape_map)
        std::replace(source.begin(), source.end(), from, to);
}
int main() {
    std::string s = "need to escape \" , \\ and \n .";
    std::cout<<s;
    escape(s, {
            {{"\n"}, {"\\n"}},
            {{"\\"}, {"\\\\"}},
            {{"\""}, {"\\\""}}
    });
}
```

But when i compile i get

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('char' and 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>')
        if (*__first == __old_value)
```

Comment: `std::replace` iterates the string, meaning it looks at `source` char by char. So it expects chars for `from` and `to` as well.

Comment: @super thanks, but is there a way to make it works fine?...

Comment: You can use `std::string::find` to find substrings, then `std::string::replace` to replace them.

Comment: Didn't you ask this very question 20 minutes earlier but deleted it after I mentioned that the problem with using `std::replace` instead of my proposed `std::string::replace` is that the elements `std::replace` will try to replace are `char`s and that `char = string` will never work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, then you can [std::string::replace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) for this. Replace the `std::replace` call with

```
source.replace(source.find(from), from.length(), to);
```

Note that if you want to replace *multiple* occurrences of a sub-string, you'll have to call replace in a loop.

```
auto f = source.find(from, 0);
while (f != std::string::npos)  // while sub-string can be replaced
{
  source.replace(f, from.length(), to);  // replace sub-string
  f = source.find(from, f); // search from position of replaced string
}
```

If you want to continue the search from *after* the replaced string, the second line in the for loop needs to be

```
f = source.find(from, f + to.length());
```

If you want a terser solution, you could do multiple replacements in the same statement with

```
source = std::regex_replace(source, std::regex{from}, to);
```

but note that the repeated construction of `std::regex` will slow things down.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning is that you can pass a second parameter to find, telling it from which index to start the search. Handy when you want to search for mutiple occureances of the same substring.

Comment: `f + 1` should be either `f` to re-search the new characters inserted from `to`, or `f + to.length()` to skip the inserted characters.

Answer (score 1):

Or use code like this?

```
inline std::string escape(const std::string& source) {
    std::string res;
    for (const char ch : source) {
        switch(ch) {
            default: res += ch; break;
            case '\n': res += "\\n"; break;
            case '\\': res += "\\\\"; break;
            case '\"': res += "\\\""; break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "need to escape \" , \\ and \n and \\ .";
    std::cout<<s;
    s = escape(s);
    std::cout<<"\nfinal string: " << s;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i'll try, but i've already solved with you previous code removing the escape from the list of the elements to escape, and escaping it at the beginning

Comment: @Berto99:  this code will run faster as code I poster [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61036311/7267525).